# Allow printing of sheets but not the entire workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with over 20 sheets that each contain many text box dans other objects. Since my worksheets have resize percentages different from 100% in layout, The objects move when printing the entire workbook. However, when printing each sheets individually, nothing moves. The code I have so far prevents from printing anything, but I would like to allow printing individual sheets:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
  MsgBox "Veuillez imprimer chaque feuille individuellement." & vbLf & "Please print each sheet individually."
  Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I would need to insert code that verify what is being printed (workbook or worksheet). Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What if you have a loop that goes through each sheet, and prints that sheet? Will it still mess up the formatting?

Comment: I do have a Macro for printing. I could just block all printing and force user to use the Macro easily. I just wanted to let the user the possibility to print using all the options available in Excel EXCEPT the workbook.printout